# State variable returning an error when WATCH on IE browser

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hello I am having an issue on the state on IE browser when i am putting it on watch function.It is a boolean variable
[image: Error message on IE browser]

```
  computed: {
...mapState("OnePage", ["spocDetails", "isLoadedSpoc", "isImageUploadStatus"])
},
watch: {
    isLoadedSpoc() {
      this.changeSpocImage();
    },
}
```

Comment: what is the body of the `changeSpocImage()` method?

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support ES6. Change your code to this:

```
watch: {
    isLoadedSpoc: function() {
      this.changeSpocImage();
    },
}
```

Comment: do you have any other methods with the new syntax in this component?

Comment: What do you meant other methods with new syntax?

Comment: Is the error for the same method? Are you getting error for other methods in the component?

Comment: no only this one that is why i am confused i also using other state in watch but it is working.

Comment: the only difference in them is the other one is not Boolean but that should not be an issue right?

Comment: i tried changing it to other value but still having the same issue any ideas?

Comment: can you may be try and post your whole component in the question?